# Form CSS wont change

Tags: html, css

I am trying to add an image to my email input field and change some coloring. Any changes to my CSS won't make a change at all in my code. My CSS page is linked correctly as well. The CSS I added below was added, after adding this CSS code, any other changes won't be made. Any help is appreciated.

HTML:

```
<article>
<h3>Information</h3>

<p>
<label for="firstName">First Name:</label>
<input type="text" name="firstName" id="firstName">
</p>

<p>
<label for="lastName">Last Name:</label>
<input type="text" name="lastName" id="lastName">
</p>

<p>
<label for="userEmail">Email:</label>
<input type="email" name="userEmail" id="userEmail">
</p>

<p>
<label for="userPassword">Password:</label>
<input type="password" name="userPassword" id="userPassword">
</p>

<h3>Questionair</h3>

<p>
<label for="textInfo">Why do you want to adopt?:</label>
<textarea cols="30" rows="5" id="textInfo"></textarea>
<p>&nbsp;</p>

<fieldset>
    <legend>What type of animal are you looking to adopt?</legend>

   <label><input type="radio" name="dog" value="dog" id="dog">Dog</label>
    <br>

   <label><input type="radio" name="cat" value="cat" id="cat">Cat</label>
<br>

  <label><input type="radio" name="bird" value="bird" 
id="bird">Bird</label>
    <br>
</fieldset>

<p>&nbsp;</p>

<fieldset>
   <legend>Choose a gender?</legend>

   <label><input type="checkbox" name="male" value="male" 
   id="male">Male</label>
   <br>

    <label><input type="checkbox" name="female" value="female" 
  id="female">Female</label>
 <br>

   <label><input type="checkbox" name="either" value="either" 
    id="either">Dosent Matter</label>
    <br>
  </fieldset>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>

   <p>
   <label for="otherPets"> Do you own other pets?</label>
   <select name="otherPets" id="otherPets">
     <option value="hasOtherPets">Yes</option>
     <option value="noOtherPets">No</option>
   </select>
  </p>

   <p>
     <input type="submit" id="submitForm" value="Submit">
   </p>

</article>
</form>
```

CSS:

the input block was added and changes were made accordingly, the code under that (starting at input [type=submit] is where CSS stopped changing after the code was created.

```
input { 
font-size: 120%; 
color: #5a5854; 
background-color: #f2f2f2; 
border: 1px solid #bdbdbd; 
border-radius: 5px; 
padding: 5px 5px 5px 30px; 
background-repeat: no-repeat; 
background-position: 8px 9px; 
display: block; 
margin-bottom: 10px;
} 

input:focus { 
background-color: #ffffff; 
border: 1px solid #b1e1e4;
}

input [type= submit] {
    background-color: #E88940;
    color: #FFEBCD;
}   

input #userEmail { 
background-image: url("../Images/mail.png");
}
```

Comment: So you're saying the CSS file is linked correctly but any changes to the file won't change anything on the page?

Comment: Let's start with some basic debugging. Have you cleared the browser's cache? Tried different browsers?

Comment: Do you have `<form>`?

Comment: @Keith correct, I double checked to make sure the file was linked correctly and it is. I was also working on this page before the form and changes were made fine.  I do have a form I must have missed copying the top part

Comment: do you have any errors in the console?

Comment: @Keith no errors in the console. Also checked under a validator and see no errors in my CSS

Comment: @CliffordStorm Then it must be the HTML.

Comment: Makes sense, I just don't know how or were since I haven't touched the HTML in a bit.

Answer (score 1):

It's the CSS that's wrong. `input #userEmail` is not accepted. That difference makes a huge effect on the page. Even though it's a tiny mistake, to correct it `input#userEmail` does what you need. What went wrong was just a simple typographic error in CSS.

**EDIT**: When I tried your HTML in JSFiddle, I see a error that says `Missing </p>` at the end. Turns out you started a paragraph and never ended it.

This is the correct HTML and CSS:

```css
input { 
font-size: 120%; 
color: #5a5854; 
background-color: #f2f2f2; 
border: 1px solid #bdbdbd; 
border-radius: 5px; 
padding: 5px 5px 5px 30px; 
background-repeat: no-repeat; 
background-position: 8px 9px; 
display: block; 
margin-bottom: 10px;
} 

input:focus { 
background-color: #ffffff; 
border: 1px solid #b1e1e4;
}

input[type=submit] {
    background-color: #E88940;
    color: #FFEBCD;
}   

input#userEmail { 
background-image: url("../Images/mail.png");
}
```

```html
<form>
<article>
<h3>Information</h3>

<p>
<label for="firstName">First Name:</label>
<input type="text" name="firstName" id="firstName">
</p>

<p>
<label for="lastName">Last Name:</label>
<input type="text" name="lastName" id="lastName">
</p>

<p>
<label for="userEmail">Email:</label>
<input type="email" name="userEmail" id="userEmail">
</p>

<p>
<label for="userPassword">Password:</label>
<input type="password" name="userPassword" id="userPassword">
</p>

<h3>Questionair</h3>

<p>
<label for="textInfo">Why do you want to adopt?:</label>
<textarea cols="30" rows="5" id="textInfo"></textarea>
</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>

<fieldset>
    <legend>What type of animal are you looking to adopt?</legend>

   <label><input type="radio" name="dog" value="dog" id="dog">Dog</label>
    <br>

   <label><input type="radio" name="cat" value="cat" id="cat">Cat</label>
<br>

  <label><input type="radio" name="bird" value="bird" 
id="bird">Bird</label>
    <br>
</fieldset>

<p>&nbsp;</p>

<fieldset>
   <legend>Choose a gender?</legend>

   <label><input type="checkbox" name="male" value="male" 
   id="male">Male</label>
   <br>

    <label><input type="checkbox" name="female" value="female" 
  id="female">Female</label>
 <br>

   <label><input type="checkbox" name="either" value="either" 
    id="either">Dosent Matter</label>
    <br>
  </fieldset>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>

   <p>
   <label for="otherPets"> Do you own other pets?</label>
   <select name="otherPets" id="otherPets">
     <option value="hasOtherPets">Yes</option>
     <option value="noOtherPets">No</option>
   </select>
  </p>

   <p>
     <input type="submit" id="submitForm" value="Submit">
   </p>

</article>
</form>
```

Comment: I removed the space but nothing changed

Comment: Try to also remove the space between the `=` sign and the `submit`.

Comment: I did that as well and still nothing :(

Comment: Well for me it works fine after removing the space. What is the browser you're currently using and the version of it?

Comment: Oh, I get it. `font-size` cannot be more than 100%.

Comment: Chrome and version 75.0.3770.100

Comment: So changing font-size does change on my browser but other code below still isn't showing.

Comment: Have you experienced problems like this before?

Comment: I haven't had a problem like this before. I also tried my code on firefox and still the same issue

Comment: I would check developer tools and then click on a div that would have a style you are looking for. If the style isn't applied, then it's got to be that the styling class doesn't match the HTML

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick.
You just need to remove the whitespace between your property selector and or ID..

```css
input { 
font-size: 120%; 
color: #5a5854; 
background-color: #f2f2f2; 
border: 1px solid #bdbdbd; 
border-radius: 5px; 
padding: 5px 5px 5px 30px; 
background-repeat: no-repeat; 
background-position: 8px 9px; 
display: block; 
margin-bottom: 10px;
} 

input:focus { 
background-color: #ffffff; 
border: 1px solid #b1e1e4;
}

input[type=submit] {
    background-color: #E88940;
    color: #FFEBCD;
}   

input#userEmail { 
background-image: url("../Images/mail.png");
}
```

Comment: What should do the trick and why? Instead of making us play spot the difference, please explain your answer.